# Jsch slower on 64 bit?

Tags: java, windows, 64-bit, jsch

We are looking at running our existing Java app on a 64 bit Windows OS and JVM instead of the current 32 bit app.  We noticed that the JSCH SFTP connection takes 15 seconds when run on the 64 bit server vs. a second on 32 bit.  Any ideas why we would see this?

Comment: This sounds like a DNS issue and possibly nothing to do with the JVM.  Does telnetting to the ssh port from both boxes take the same time?

Comment: There is no reason inherent in JSch that would make it significantly slower on a 64-bit JVM.